# Generate Page Title and Meta Tags from database using URL path

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I want to dynamically change the title tag by getting the name from the database. This internal database already has the name and ID in the same table but I'm having trouble.

What I wish to do is get the QRLinkCode from the Url Path and then return the Name associated with that QRLinkCode to populate the title meta tag in the view source.

This is what I have written so far.

```
     public class PageMetaDetails
            {
                public static string UpdateMetaDetails (string urlpath)
                {
                    //--- StringBuilder object to store MetaTags information.
                    StringBuilder sbMetaTags = new StringBuilder();
        
                    //--Step1 Get data from database.
        
                    using (TemplateDBEntities db = new TemplateDBEntities())
                    {
                       
                        var qrLinkName = "";
                        
                        
                         if (urlpath.StartsWith("/ItemList"))
                        {
                            //get qrLink code out of the url
                            var qrLinkId = urlpath.Substring(urlpath.Length - 6);
        
        
                            //hit the database for this qr link by id
                            var qrLink = db.QRLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QRLinkCode == qrLinkId);
                            qrLinkName = qrLink.Name;
                            
                            
        
                        }
                        
        
                        //---- Step2 In this step we will add <title> tag to our StringBuilder Object.
                        //sbMetaTags.Append(qrLinkName);
                        //sbMetaTags.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        
                        
                        return qrLinkName;
                    }
        
                    
                }
                
               
            }
```

> There is code that will go in between this that's why its not there
> are extra {} but I just want to get this part working first.

I also have this below in the Layout.cshtml to route the name to the title meta tag.

```
<title>
        @{string title = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] + "/" + Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
            @(Html.Raw(Models.PageMetaDetails.UpdateMetaDetails(title)));} </title>
```

For some reason its not returning the name associated with the ID. If anyone has any idea let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried step by step debugging? Is there any error message?

Comment: I have tried step by step debugging and don't receive any error messages. That's why I am so confused.

Comment: I'm kinda wondering if the razor pages is coded incorrectly or if I'm not routing to the url path properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently there was something wrong the url path string so I corrected my input.

```
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/ItemList"))
                {
                    //get qrLink code out of the url
                    //var qrLinkId = urlpath.Substring(urlpath.Length - 6);
                    
                    var qrLinkId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Length - 6);
                   

                    //hit the database for this qr link by id
                    var qrLink = db.QRLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QRLinkCode == qrLinkId);
                    qrLinkName = qrLink.Name;
                    // var orgId = qrLink.FKId;

                    

                }
```

which allowed the return of the title associated with the QR Code in the url substring.

Comment: What specifically was wrong with your original code?

Comment: I'm guessing that the URL substring request was incorrect.

Comment: Hi Renarldo Mason, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)